# Gitlab-CI Runner on EKS with AWS IAM Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I would like to use EKS to host Gitlab-CI Runners which will deploy my infrastructure on AWS.
I would like the pod created but gitlab manager to be able to assume the right IAM role when the job is triggered so the team that deploys it's infrastructure only access to its own account.
Is that faisable using gitlab-ci runner please ?

Many thanks;

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you absolutely can scope your CI job access to appropriate AWS roles.

Ideally, by default your **job** environment should be *unprivileged* -- no AWS roles or AWS credentials at all. The runner executing the job should receive the credentials only when the job actually runs. For example, by retrieving credentials from a secret storage service, such as [Vault secrets](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/#use-vault-secrets-in-a-ci-job), or similar.

One of the best ways to do this with AWS is to [use OIDC to retrieve temporary credentials](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_services/aws/) when the job runs.

1. Create an IAM role with appropriately scoped permissions
2. Configure the role to be assumed with GitLab web identity (`CI_JOB_JWT_V2`) with appropriate condition(s) to match the corresponding project(s)/branches, or other attributes.
3. Configure the GitLab job to run `aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity ...` to acquire the temporary role credentials
4. Access AWS and perform deployments using the temporary credentials.

The builtin `CI_JOB_JWT_V2` allows you to assume the appropriate role.

Another option may be to simply add AWS credentials to your CICD variables for each project, but this is not ideal.

Comment: thanks for this answer which look working as expected.
However, I wanted to use the ROLE ARN to attach it to the pod where the CI will run.
So my problem here is, how do I attach the right role to the right pod when I have many different teams

Comment: @Ahmed-F Yeah, can't be done with the GitLab-provided executors, unfortunately. You can configure a specific role in the runner settings, but the value is static. You could create multiple runners for every role and lock them to respective groups/projects, but that's usually inefficient. In principle, you could write a custom executor for this, but you'd have to write it all yourself.

Comment: Indeed storing aws credentials as variables is not ideal. In January 2023 CircleCI was hacked, all customer keys were compromised, including the master encryption key. Short lived tokens like the ones generated by OIDC are the safest option.